# select in NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have Person. All Person have many addresses (one-to-many). 
I need to do select from Person data, that contains List of Addresses.
I use ICriteria ,because I use the projection.
How can I do it???
And what mapping I need??
Thanks

Comment: what means: "that contains List of Addresses"? Do you want to load persons which contain at least one address or every address from a list of addresses?

Comment: Why do you need criteria because of projection?? The projection is simply the select clause in HQL.

Comment: We are eager to help here, but could you please put some more effort into the question? What are your current mappings and classes (simplified)? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487057/linq-to-nhibernate-like-in-operator). if i understand correctly, it may help.